# How to access placeholder properties from thymeleaf view?

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I using kolorobot MVC archetype f https://github.com/kolorobot/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype in my project.

This is my configuration of properties placeholder

```
@Bean
public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
    ppc.setLocations(new ClassPathResource[] { 
            new ClassPathResource("/config/website.properties"),
            new ClassPathResource("/persistence.properties") });
    return ppc;
}
```

This is how I pass properties to view

```
...
@Value("${facebook.fanpage.url}")
private String facebookFanpageUrl;
...
model.addAttribute("fanpage", facebookFanpageUrl);
```

It is working fine. But I was wondering if there is any quickest way, to directly access properties from placeholder? For example as it is here     @Value("${facebook.fanpage.url}").